# Understanding Decorator design pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm having a problem understanding decorator design pattern. Let's say I want to use it in my project. It is a platform game so I immediately thought the best usage would be on enemy classes. I would like to have different types of enemies, the basic one and the others that would be extensions of the first one (e.g with different attributes, colours, additional AI logic). From my understanding this is how classes should look like

```
abstract class Enemy{

    float speedX,speedY;
    int x,y,width,height;
    COLOR colour;
    Sprite sprite;

    void setAnimation();
    void update();
    void render();
    void init();

}


class EnemyBasic extends Enemy{

  EnemyBasic() {
        init();
    }

    void init() {
        //set all variables
    }
    @Override
    void setAnimation() {
        //set animation
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        //update
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        render(sprite,colour,x,y,width,height)

    }
}

class FastEnemy extends Enemy{

    Enemy basicEnemy;
    FastEnemy(Enemy basicEnemy) {
        this.basicEnemy = basicEnemy;
        init();
    }

    void init() {
        basicEnemy.init();
        maximalSpeed = basicEnemy.maximalSpeed*2;
    }
    @Override
    void setAnimation() {
        basicEnemy.setAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        basicEnemy.update();
        additionalMovementLogic();
    } 

    additionalMovementLogic(){
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        color=green;
        basicEnemy.render()

    }
}
```

The problem is, this wouldn't work because methods calls from `basicEnemy` object would operate on EnemyBasic fields and not those from EnemyFast.So for example render() would render EnemyBasic object and not EnemyFast. Only solution that I can see is to reimplement the whole class but what is the point of decorator class then? Am I understanding something wrong ? Or in this case decorator shouldn't be used ? And if so when it should be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current form this doesn't look like a good use case for Decorator Pattern, because it would require altering internal behaviour of basicEnemy. I can think of following solution:

- Create getters and setters (i.e. for speed, colour)
- Extract rendering into separate class

This way renderer can get decorated values, for example:

1. Renderer asks for speed.
2. Decorator calls getSpeed() on basicEnemy and multiplies it by 2.
3. Renderer handles rendering logic.

Comment: But this way I would have to create getters for each and every field that renders uses (like coordinates, sprite picture and so on). So I think I get it now - Decorator can only extend functionality of given class and not alter it. This said this is not good use case for Decorator Pattern

Comment: Yes. Decorator Pattern works best if you want to alter something that is passed / returned by the wrapped object, but not the internal behaviour of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an implementation of the decorator pattern -- it's just subclassing.  You may be able to use the decorator pattern for your purpose, but instead I suggest you look into Entity-Component-System:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system

This is a design pattern that is widely used in game development to solve just the kinds of problems that you are trying to solve.  Check out the above article and the external links at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You are in kind of a correct track for implementing ***Decorator pattern***. But you have to be careful about, what your real requirement is.

From your code, I hope you are going to try out something like this;

```
Enemy enemy = new EnemyFast(new EnemyBasic());
```

This really makes sense only if **EnemyFast class behaviors = EnemyBasic class behaviors + some additions**.

So for example, in your `render()` method inside `EnemyFast` class should look like this (same goes to other polymorphic methods).

***Note***: the field name inside class EnemyFast should change from `basicEnemy` into `enemy`. In that sense, it would sound more generic.

```
    @Override
    public void render() {
        enemy.render(); //renderlogic of basic enemy
        //implement additional logic you want, so that it would fill upto EnemyFast    
    }
```

So for your last question, Decorator pattern is a solution outlining **object evolution**. Rather being too rigid from adopting purely inheritance, Decorator pattern tells us to encapsulate the evolutionary methods and reuse them with use of composition which gives us more flexibility. If we did this solely with inheritance (going down and down with inheritance hierarchy), some child classes coming later would have to inherit all the methods of their parent classes which may not be needed at all (That's the reason why inheritance is a too rigid way). So ***Decorator pattern*** is also a perfect example of using [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) (composition/aggregation).

Comment: My point was even when I do call enemy.render() method, there would be a object of type EnemyBasic rendering ,with EnemyBasic attributes like sprite picture, coordinates and so on, and then my "addition" method would run with EnemyFast attributes.

Comment: @user3713267 ^ i dnt get this.

Comment: ok let's say my EnemyBasic default coordinates are `int x=100,y=200;` and EnemyFast which has different set of same variables has int `x=300;y=500;` Now when I do `Enemy enemy = new EnemyFast( new EnemyBasic() ); enemy.draw();` It would be drawn on coordinates 100,200 because my (EnemyFast) draw() method will call (EnemyBasic) draw() method which takes enemyBasic coordinates and then draws on them. Not sure if this clears anything :x